# Проверка есть ли в value input в массиве

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет всем условие задачи такое если ключ который есть в массиве `a7` был введен в `i-7` выводит цифру `1` если нет то `0`
Вот что я написал прошу помочь найти ошибку

```
let a7 = {
    "b": 17,
    "e": 22
};


function f7() {
    let x = document.querySelector('.i-7');
    let y = document.querySelector('.out-7');
    let g = '';
    if (a7[x] !== undefined) {
        g += 1;
    }
    else {
        g += 0;
    }
    y.innerHTML = g 
}
document.querySelector('.b-7').onclick = f7;



    <div class="form-control">Input i-7 <input type="text" class="i-7"></div>
    <button class="button-primary b-7">Task-7</button>
    <div class="out-7"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Простите был невнимателен ответ прост нужно в `let x = document.querySelector('.i-7');`
дописать `let x = document.querySelector('.i-7').value;`